# Difference between window's properties and global variable

Tags: javascript, object, var, ecmascript-5

I try to run a code below in browser. I thought property `window.a` and global `a` is the same cell in memory. Could somebody please give me a link to an article which explains this behaviour.

```
// undefined
// if (window.a) {}

// Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
// if (a) {}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They are the same:

```
a = 1;
a === window.a // true
```

Edit: Sorry, was a bit too quick there... I diddnt answer anything. This article explains the difference pretty well:
https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/

"A Reference is considered unresolvable if its base value is undefined"

```
window.a // base value is window, reference object is a
a // base value is a
```

Comment: The question contains code showing different behaviour for the two variables. The asker knows that the two references will be equal if `a` is set, they are asking why they behave differently when `a` is not set.

Answer (score 0):

`window` is an object, and trying to access a key that's not been set on an object always returns `undefined`, even if the variable `a` has not been set.

```
var a = {}
a.b
>>> undefined
```

The difference is that `a` does a variable lookup (and fails, because you didn't define it), and `window.a` does a property lookup on the `window` object, which returns `undefined`.

Comment: I understand it. But when I try to get global variable, actually return property from the global object.